# How best to accumulate variables with a const member?

Tags: c++

The following won't work, because `Int` has a const member and the `=` operator is deleted since it can't modify the value:

```
struct Int {
    const int val = 1;
    Int(int val) : val(val) {}
    operator int() {
        return val;
    }
};

std::vector<Int> ints = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Int sum = 0;
for (Int i : ints) { sum = sum+i; }
std::cout << sum;
```

The same issue occurs if I try to use `std::accumulate`.

I could get around this by making `sum` a smart pointer, but it looks quite clumsy. Is there a better way?

Comment: `sum` cannot have a const member. How do you expect to modify it (by accumulating into it) otherwise ?

Comment: sum::val is definitively constant, once initialized it won't change, you have designed it like that. What is your goal : initialize ```sum``` with an accumulation then not touch it afterward? If so their will be solution. Clarify your goal in order to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: This is somehow contradictory - having a `const` member vs. the intention to modify instances, isn't it? (AFAIR, this can somehow be tricked with placement `new`, but to me, it looks like broken by design.)

Comment: Maybe, you're looking for something like [immer](https://github.com/arximboldi/immer)? ;-)

Comment: @Oersted I have a list of objects of a type that has some const member, and I want to get an object of the same type which some sort of accumulation of the list, for example a sum.

Comment: @H.v.M Can you please clarify your use case in your question,  and why that class member needs to be `const`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not looking for the solution "make it non-const", and there's no need to make the question overly specific.

Comment: What is your actual assignment or exercise? What are its requirements? What are its limitations? Please [edit] your question to include a full and complete copy-paste of your assignment or exercise text.

Comment: @H.v.M. Sounds like an xy-problem for me so far. In that specific case you could simply accumulate the sum with a regular `int`, and construct a new `Int` from it as result.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Suppose the use-case is that I'd love to remove the `const` but I can't for whatever reason.

Comment: @H.v.M. you probably oversimplified the problem in your question.

Comment: `const` and reference members are almost always a design mistake.

Comment: @H.v.M if the goal is to have wrapped int that are initialised at compile time, I would merely go for a constexpr int (no need for struct Int) and initialize it with a constexpr function (yet might be tricky if the source data are in a ```vector``` because it's not very friendly with ```constexpr```; maybe with C++20 where some ```constexpr``` API is defined for ```vector```)

Comment: `Int` has no `operator+()`, so that's another reason it won't work.  Just use `long sum` and `sum += i.val`.

Comment: *I'd love to remove the const but I can't for whatever reason* Can you add `auto operator=(Int from) -> Int& { std::destroy_at(this); new (this) Int{from}; return *this; }`?  (Not sure if a `launder` is needed in that mess.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a list of objects of a type that has some const member, and I
> want to get an object of the same type which some sort of accumulation
> of the list, for example a sum.
>
> I'm not looking for the solution "make
> it non-const", and there's no need to make the question overly
> specific.

**Conceptually**, this can be done by a left (or right) fold, which is simply a recursive call and does not involve any assignment. Here is the [cppreference page for fold_left_first in C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/fold_left_first).

> Left-folds the elements of given range, that is, returns the result of
> evaluation of the chain expression: f(f(f(f(x1, x2), x3), ...), xn),

However, the `fold_left_first` from standard library still requires `std::movable<T>`, which in turn requires `std::assignable_from<T&, T>`, and `Int` would fail for this constraint, so it cannot be directly used here even if we have C++23.

Still, it is possible to write your own version of `fold_left_first` without those constraints as follows:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

struct Int {
    const int val = 1;
    Int(int val) : val(val) {}
    operator int() {
        return val;
    }
    Int operator+(const Int& other) const{
        return val + other.val;
    }
};

template <typename R, typename F>
auto fold_left_first(R&& range, F&& f){
    if(std::ranges::empty(range)){
        return std::optional<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>{};
    }
    else if(std::ranges::size(range) == 1){
        return std::optional{*std::ranges::begin(range)};
    }
    else{
        return std::optional{
            std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), 
                *fold_left_first(
                    std::ranges::subrange(std::ranges::begin(range), std::ranges::prev(std::ranges::end(range))), 
                    std::forward<F>(f)
                ), 
                *std::ranges::prev(std::ranges::end(range))
            )
        };
    }
}

int main(){
    std::vector<Int> ints = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::cout << fold_left_first(ints, std::plus<>{})->val << std::endl;
    //Also works for rvalue
    std::cout << fold_left_first(std::vector<Int>{1, 2, 3, 4}, std::plus<>{})->val << std::endl;
}
```

The `fold_left_first` follows the same semantics as the std version and returns an `std::optional` to indicate a potentially empty range. You may adapt it to suit your needs.

However, as others have commented, it is generally adviced that const and reference members be avoided, but since you have stated that removing them is not an option, this is the best I can get without losing generality.

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Kojc1MvKr

Answer (score 8):

> The same issue occurs if I try to use `std::accumulate`.

No it does not, if you just use it right.

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
struct Int {
    const int val = 1;
    Int(int val) : val(val) {}
    operator int() {
        return val;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Int> v{1,2,3,4};
    auto x = Int(std::accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0,[](int accu,const Int& i) { return accu + i.val;}));    
    std::cout << x;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gv5TqMWa7)

Return type and the `accu` can be of different type than the elements. The return type is determined from the initial value `0` and is `int`.

---

The same you could do in your handwritten loop:

```
std::vector<Int> v{1,2,3,4};
Int sum = [&v](){
    int temp = 0;
    for (const auto& e : v) temp += e.val;
    return temp;
}();
```

---

If you want to modify members, don't make them `const`. Though, you do not need to modify it to accumulate it. Also, `operator int` should be `const`.

---

> Suppose the use-case is that I'd love to remove the const but I can't for whatever reason.

Then the solution is to not use `Int`. It can be considered broken for more than one reason.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a concept (e.g. move semantics are missing) but you can create a wrapper which creates/destroys objects on demand/assignment.

Of course, if constructors/destructors are not cheap, this solution will not be magically cheaper either.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Immutable {
    Immutable(T value) { new (&m_value) T(std::move(value)); }

    Immutable& operator=(const Immutable& o) {
        if (&o != this) {
            std::destroy_at(std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(&m_value)));
            new (&m_value) T(o.m_value);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Immutable& operator=(const T& o) {
        std::destroy_at(std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(&m_value)));
        new (&m_value) T(o);

        return *this;
    }

    ~Immutable() {
        std::destroy_at(std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(&m_value)));
    }

    operator T() const {
        return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&m_value));
    }

    const T& value() const {
        return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&m_value));
    }

    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> m_value;
};
```

```
struct Int {
    const int val = 1;
    Int(int val) : val(val) {}
    operator int() const { return val; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Int> ints = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    Immutable<Int> sum{0};
    for (Int i : ints) {
        sum = sum.value() + i;
    }
    std::cout << sum.value();
}
```

Comment: You should use `std::optional` under the hood. Manual lifetime management is tricky to get right (e.g. what if placement-new in the `operator=` throws?).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I totally forgot about `std::optional`, yea, that is much simpler.

Comment: How does `std::optional` work around the limitations imposed from an object with a const member variable?

Comment: @Eljay Because it stores the object the same way as my `Immutable` and offers `.reset()`  and `.emplace` methods that can perform destruction, (re)construction instead of raw `delete` and placement new.

Comment: Hmm, I was unable to get `.emplace` to work.  I'm probably doing something wrong.  I look forward to an update to your answer using `optional`!